# floating action button is not working on next activity

Tags: java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_1, container, false);

        fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent AskQuestionIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), AskQuestion.class);
                startActivity(AskQuestionIntent);
            }
        });
        return view;

    }
```

floating action button is not working on next activity
when click floating button then application close

Comment: are you getting `fab` on each activity?

Comment: no only main activity